# Flutter many aligned buttons in a stack don't work

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I'm currently stacking buttons in flutter using

```
Transform.scale(
    scale: 0.5,
    child: Stack(
      children: List.generate(data.length, (int index) {

        Alignment alignment = alignments[index];
        String message = messages[index];

        return Align(
          alignment: Alignment(
              alignment.x,
              alignment.y
          ),
          child: SizedBox(
            key: UniqueKey(),
            width: 100.0,
            height: 100.0,
            child: MaterialButton(
              key: UniqueKey(),
              onPressed: () {
                print("Specific message: "+message.toString());
              },
              child: Container(
                width: 100.0,
                height: 100.0,
                color: Colors.pink,
                child: Text("message: "+message.toString()),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }),
    ),
)
```

However this only works for the first few handful of widgets, the later widgets no longer print the message or register the click.

====

Side note I have just tested where alignment is `Alignment(0.0, 0.0)` and the top button works. However, when it has alignment away from the centre it doesn't work.

====

I have a suspicion if a button is built initially off screen you won't be able to press it even if you scale the whole screen.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, the issue is coming because of using `Transform`, can you include full widget that will reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0):

To fix the problem all the buttons need to be on the screen at `scale: 1.0`